# C Language One Sorting Function Chose From 2 Criteria

Tags: c, sorting, types, structure, criteria

I was wondering how could I use a single sort function that does the sorting choosing from 2 different criteria. 
    I was thinking to implement the sort function(Sort) having a pointer to another function(Criteria) as an argument. That function Criteria provides me either the (let's say) name or the age of a student, using structures. So a single function that returns two types of data. I think it has to be a void. I want to use bubble sort but I have no idea on how to implement the Criteria function since I want it to return either a char or an int value.

Comment: You could refer to the prototype of `qsort()`.

Comment: with `qsort()` the decision of how to make the comparison is in the `compare()` function that you write. everything else stays the same..  The `compare()` function would be a if/else on which field to sort on.  Then have some global indication that your set to select which kind of comparison to make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Behave like qsort

qsort solves the problem by taking a pointer to a comparison function that takes two pointers to structures (left and right) and compares the values pointed at:

```
compare( left, right ){
  if( left->field < right->field )
     return -1;
  if( left->field > right->field )
     return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

The types left and right are passed in as `void*` but cast to concrete types.
Different implementations of compare give different fields.

### variant structure

The alternative is a union / struct

```
 struct data {
    enum Types type;
    union {
        double dblVal;
        int    intVal;
        ....;
    } u;
 };
```

The type signals the type of data in the union, and the members can then be appropriately read.

This is the approach taken by `lua` for its type system.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I will try to implement some parts of this idea even though is doesn't exactly suit my needs and it outlines the area of knowledge we have to use in class. More specifically, I need the function that I can use as an argument for the sorting function, This function I am looking for has to return either the age or the name criteria so the sorting function could know wich one to select. :D Thank you again!

Comment: @ConstantinescuCristiana: You use two different comparator functions — one does the name comparison, the other the age comparison.  At the point where you call the sort function, you pass the correct comparator for the comparison you want done this time.  This is what was meant by the "look at `qsort()`" comment.  The standard C `qsort()` function not only allows (requires) you to use different comparators, it also allows you to sort an array of any data type.  But the idea espoused here is essentially the same — the details are slightly different.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now understand :D